# Differentiating strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to be able to return `True` if letters in the first string are also included in the second string.  For example, `only_uses_letters_from("boffo","foobar")` should return `True`.  Here is what I have so far:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(x, y):
    """returns true if the first string only contains characters that are also in the second string

    str, str -> str"""
    for letter in x:
        if x in y:
            return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: Should be `str, str -> bool` btw...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [set.issubset](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) which checks if every element in a is in b:

```
a, b = "boffo", "foobar"
print(set(a).issubset(b))
True
```

So in your function:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(x, y):
     return set(x).issubset(y)
```

Or use `all`, checking every letter in `x` is `in` `b`:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(x, y):
    return all(letter in y for letter in x)
```

All will short circuit if we find a letter in x that is not in y and return False, if all letters are in y then it will return True.

If you have large data using sets can be a fast way to check if any element from one iterable is in another:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(x, y):
      st = set(y)  # O(1) lookups
      return all(letter in st for letter in x)
```

Comment: Im pretty new at python and I appreciate you taking the time to explain this to me, it actually makes sense

Comment: @JaredBanton, no prob. There is not much too it really. To be a subset of another set all your elements must be in that other set.  Using `all` basically does what it says all/every element must be in the other iterable. Both approaches are fine,  sets in particular when dealing with lookups are extremely fast so the cost of creating it is offset with larger data and can make code much more efficient.

Comment: The last method is not necessarily fast: if `x` is large and does not contain any letter from `y`, then it is very slow, as it goes linearly through the whole string `x`. I recommend the first, simple and explicit solution *unless* speed is an issue *and* typical arguments can be handled faster.

Answer (score 0):

The approach here is to check, for each character in `x`, that it is also in `y`. If there is a character for which that is not the case then the answer is `False`:

```
def only_uses_letters_from(x, y):
    for c in x:
        if c not in y:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: This solution does manually what `all()` is meant to be used for (see Padraic's solution). Concretely, this means that using this solution misses a shorter and more legible way of doing the same thing (more efficiently, probably, on top of that).

Comment: @EOL yes, but this answer helps to see why the initial code doesn't work. I don't think every SO answer is for replacing code with a stdlib call.

Comment: Indeed it helps see why the initial code does not work, but the question seeks to "return True if letters in the first string are also included in the second string": I would not recommend to anybody a solution that ignores a simple and powerful Python feature that makes code easier to read and write.

Comment: @EOL: maybe, but at the same time the attitude here at SO is becoming more towards showing off "how one should code" rather than helping people writing for loops and if statements.

Comment: Helping people is good indeed. However, it is fundamental to answer the questions as asked: if the question had been about how to code a loop, then yes, showing how to do it would be perfect. Furthermore, while I can understand your frustration, people who answer with good programming practices do not necessarily "show off"; in any case they do contribute to a subject that is arguably not being taught enough—and has a huge cost in terms of productivity. Maybe this explains the shift here at SO!

Answer (score 0):

Your code logic has a problem, if the first letter is in the string, it will return true right away. The following code would work:

```
def foo(x, y):
    for letter in x:
        if letter not in y:
            return  False
    return  True

print foo("booffo", "foobar")
```

Answer (score -1):

**Pythonic way:**

```
def only_uses_letters_from(str1, str2):
    return all(letter in str2 for letter in str1)
```

This conveys the your logic and makes it readable.

**Don't optimize with set() for large strings!**

There are some suggestions to preprocess one of the string with set() to optimize the search when strings are large. This is wrong. Searching in set is faster but creating the set itself is a lot slower then just searching in string.

Using `timeit` shows that creating a set from a string with 1.000.000 letters takes around 50ms on my machine and just running the original function takes less than 1 ms.

```
python -m timeit -n 1000 -s setup='str2 = "".join("abc" for i in xrange(1000000))' 'set(str2)'
```

Comment: The timing result would probably give the opposite result if `str1` contained many letters and none of them is in the very long string `str2`, because in this case, without set, Python has to go through each of the million characters in `str2` before deciding that each character from `str1` is not found. So, I believe that your statement about not using `set()` is only appropriate in certain situations.